# SlugRelatedField doesn't work with a list of object

Tags: django-rest-framework

for a project I'm working with django rest api. My problem is that from the frontend I receive a json list of cities. These cities are already contained in a database table, so I used a many-to-many relationship to avoid redundancy. What I want is for each city in the list to be associated with a specific itinerary: all itineraries can contain that city and each city has a unique id so by doing some research I discovered that SlugRelatedField was right for me. The problem is that, however, when the data is valid in the view with the serializer I receive an error, that is, the json list is not seen as a list but as a string. Can you help me? I attach screenshots.[Serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYYms.png) [View that use the serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMLZR.png) [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUGKU.png)

The error when I try to insert an itinerary says "`{"visited_cities": ["Object with name=['Roccarainola'] does not exist."]}`". I tried do create a mock up adding only the name of the city (Roccarainola) and it works..Why? Did I misunderstand how it works? Thanks :)